# Error Connect MySQL Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database from Data Fusion, but I am getting the following error. Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. The database is accessed through public IP through port 3306, from my machine I can connect perfectly, but from Data Fusion I cannot.

[image]

Comment: What is `my machine`. The error message typically means that a firewall is blocking access or you are specifying the wrong IP:Port connection. This is indicated by the message `The driver has not received any packets from the server. ` Without details, we can only guess.

Comment: My machine is my local computer

Answer (score 0):

As John Hanley pointed out in his comment, it's probably due to a connectivity issue with your SQL instance.

A possible reason would be that you have not enabled your instance to be connected via its public IP. If that's the case, go to your SQL instance and edit its configuration, adding a network (if you haven't done so previously) and providing an IP range to include your Data Fusion instance. Keep in mind that if you configure your instance to accept connections using its public IP address, also [configure it to use SSL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance) to keep your data secure. If that was the issue, now you should be able to connect properly.

Also, be sure to check that the Dataproc cluster that your data Fusion instance is using under the hood has the [proper configuration](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/network) (you shouldn't worry about this if you haven't changed anything about the Dataproc cluster).

This is the best advice I can give without further details. If this doesn't work for you, we're going to need more information.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

I use one windows pc with several linux box at home.
My main station is the Windows one.
I'v been using Sqlyog just to prob tables on the remote db.

I use my class C addr. to address the server.
It works well. By design I want to access the db server
from anywhere in my home...

60% to 75%ishhh problems of that kind would be related
to the .cnt file configuration.

Regards
Steph